# Jmeter - How do I output a counter variable to my csv results file?

Tags: csv, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

What I want to accomplish is to have a thread group with multiple GETS, each GET is tagged with the same thread ID, until another thread is started. The problem I have is when I hold a constant load, those thread IDs are recycled. So I thought I'll add a counter, and this way the thread unique ids will not be duplicated. Yet I have google'd and read all over the internet and tried and tried but I cannot seem to get the Counter Config to output to a variable and then have that changing variable written to my csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to trying other test platforms, you may want to take a look at NetGend.  It's easy to have many concurrent sessions and each will use a different Id. See the following example.

```
function userInit() {
    var globalId = 1;
}
function VUSER() {
    id = globalId ++;
    action(http, "http://www.example.com/?${id}");
}
```

There are lots of [blogs](http://perftestingng.blogspot.com/) showing how easy it is to script on NetGend platform.